# React js Axios Get Request in submit form

Tags: reactjs, ajax, input, get, axios

i have a simple input form where i put a list of strings , then for each element of the string (string[i]) i run an ajax Get request to my api .
so here is the ajax request :

```
async function getUsers(props){
  try{
    const response = await Axios.get(`url=`+props)
    console.log(response)
    return response;
  }catch{
  console.log("response failed")
  }
}
```

and i run it here :

```
... some code here ...



    for(var i =0; i < string.length; i++){    // map the entery     (string) 


      getUsers(string[i]).then(res => {
        this.setState({
          string2:res          // this  one is just for testing 
        });


        console.log(res.data.id);      

        mystring22.push({res});       

       console.log("me inside the promise :  " + this.state.string2.data.id);
     })


     setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("iam not empty " + this.state.string2.data.id);
      console.log(mystring22);
 /*  -----------------
        I WANT TO DO SOME WORK HERE 
   -----------------*/

    }, 3000);



    this.setState({
      string3 : mystring22
    })

... some code here ...
```

so everything works fine , and my problem is the following : 
the code take too much time (3 second for each request ) , is there is a way to change the code so it can do "SOMETHING" after each request , i tried to delete the setTimeout or reduce it but that not working the array is undefined after that .
hope you can help me .
thank you

Comment: in your getUsers async function `return response.data` instead of returning just response.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is an async function, so when you call:

```js
setState({ string2: res });
this.state.string2; // OUTDATED
```

in order to access the updated value, you must use the callback:

```js
setState({ string2: res },
  () => { console.log(this.state.string2) }); // UP TO DATE
```

as you can see in this [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-brook-j3tu9), [with the callback on line 27](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-brook-j3tu9?file=/src/App.js:652-726) and [without the callback on 33](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-brook-j3tu9?file=/src/App.js:766-833).